# How to save your git password using https

Tags: git

I am using an older version of git and cannot use credential helper.  I am trying to save my git username and password for my company's git repo but my username is my email address.

How do I add my username to below:

`git remote add origin https://username:mypassword@companygit.com/path/to/repo.git`

I keep getting an error because my username is chris@companygit.com and the '@' symbol screws up what is above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there really no reason that you can't upgrade to a version of Git that supports this feature?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark: Can you [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) `@` as `%40`?

Answer (score 0):

So earlier today when I had to do this, [this Github help document](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/) proved to be invaluable.

- You only need to pass the URL of the Git repository - not your username and password.
- If you use the `git` protocol, you won't have to authenticate to the repository every time.